# Неизвестное количество подмасок регулярного выражения PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть паттерн:

```
$pattern = '([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)([?][a-z]+[=][0-9]+)+';
```

Как вы видите, здесь присутствует 3 подмаски.

Есть строка с ссылками:

```
$path='realestate/list/$1/$2$3';
```

Есть строка url:

```
$url='/sometext/sometext?page=3?page=4?page=5';
```

Следуюущий код работает c проблемой.

```
$internalRoute = preg_replace('~^'.$pattern.'$~' ,$path, $url);
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я получаю такую строку:

```
'realestate/list/buy/houses/?page=5'
```

Хотелось бы получить

```
'realestate/list/buy/houses/?page=3?page=4?page=5'
```

Comment: Так ничего не получится, так как кол-во групп определено в регулярном выражении. У вас их всего три.

Comment: Мне казалось, что если к '([?][a-z]+[=][0-9]+)' добавить +, то выражение может повторяться не 1 раз

Comment: Оно и повторяется, только в группе сохраняется последний захваченный текст, [см. сами](https://regex101.com/r/yaJqyA/2). Может, вам нужно [вот такое выражение](https://regex101.com/r/yaJqyA/3), `([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)((?:[?][a-z]+[=][0-9]+)+)`?

Comment: $pattern = '([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)([?][a-z]+[=][0-9].)+';

Comment: Да, Wiktor Stribiżew, сойдет. Спасибо. programmer403, спс и тебе, будет над чем подумать

Comment: Денис, [отметьте мой ответ как правильный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), пожалуйста, если моё решение помогло.

Comment: Так помогло или нет? :)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте повторяющуюся подмаску незахватывающей и заключите её в захватывающую подмаску:

```
$pattern = '([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)((?:[?][a-z]+[=][0-9]+)+)';
                             ^ ^^                    ^
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/yaJqyA/3)

Таким образом, все повторяющиеся `?page=<ЧИСЛО>` окажутся в третьей группе (подмаске), и их можно будет "восстановить" с помощью `$3`.